# How to resolve cache issue in my extension for Magento Marketplace?

Tags: magento2, extensions, marketplace, submission, magento2marketplace

I'm submit my extension in Magento Marketplace. I have checked all the functionality is working also check in Magento 2 coding standard but face one issue in QA Review.

**I'm face below issue**

I'm fill up form and upload image & save in admin in check in front end **it will display only after cache flush**.

Can anyone tell me how can I display that form without cache flush. I know about **cacheable=false** but it also not accepted by Magento Marketplace.

Please suggest me a way how can I successfully pass my extension from QA.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per I know there is nothing wrong about flushing the cache from admin.Second if  your using the cacheable = false remove it instead look for other option. I was facing the same issue what I found was that I was using Session  Model instead of SessionFactory . This is just a scenario. You have to check in deep about the code and can not give you exact solution as code is not  available.

Comment: @Tanmay, Thanks for your reply. I will check & let you know if it's work.